# SQL query which counts status of grouped by month w. revision system

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, revisions

While attempting to produce a view of ticket statuses over time, I've run into a few challenges:

Background:

The database containing ticket records is setup to allow basic re-visioning, and includes the following columns (this is what I believe to be relevant):

**ID** - **original** - status - date_created - modified

Desired Solution:

A table which includes: The count of each status grouped by week/month/year.

The challenge:

Excluding any revision in which the status has not changed.

*Thanks ahead of time for any assistance, this is heating up my brain :)*

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! This was the solution that appears to have worked:

`SELECT COUNT(t1.status), month(t1.date_modified), year(t1.date_modified), week(t1.date_modified), t1.status
FROM trends as t1
JOIN trends as t2 ON (t1.original = t2.ID)
WHERE t1.status != t2.status
GROUP BY MONTH(date_modified), status;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be something like this (without the grouping by date):

```
 SELECT t1.*
 FROM table as t1
 JOIN table as t2 ON (t1.original = t2.ID)
 WHERE t1.status != t2.status;
```

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputation to vote this up, but I wish I did :) Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

A subquery with [`EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Just to help me understand how that function applies to this problem could you provide further details? (Not time sensitive:)

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question :)
Basically - `EXISTS()` is a function used in `WHERE` clause that takes a subquery (SELECT...) as an argument and returns TRUE if it returns any rows. In simple cases it performs as fast as a join doing similar work (and can be more readable and easier to write), sometimes it's slower.